# How can I make all my sprites move instead of stopping when a new one spawns?

Tags: pygame, sprite

My plan was to make circles spawn at regular intervals and go towards my mouse at a certain speed. I got the first part of this working. Although, when a new sprite is spawned, the previous one stops moving and so on as if they were not getting updated anymore. I am trying to make them all move simultaneously towards my mouse instead of just the new one.

I am fairly new, so feel free to add any other input on flaws you see.

Here is the part of code relevant to this:

```
# Enemy
class Enemy (pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0
        self.speed = 2
        self.change_x = 0
        self.change_y = 0
        self.update()

    def update(self):
        dx, dy = (pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0]+8) - self.x, (pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1]+8) - self.y
        dist = math.hypot(dx, dy)
        dx, dy = dx / dist, dy / dist
        self.change_x += dx * self.speed
        self.change_y += dy * self.speed


def make_enemies():
    enemy = Enemy()
    enemy.change_x = random.randrange(0, 800)
    enemy.change_y = random.randrange(0, 600)
    enemy.speed = 2

    return enemy


enemy_list = []
spawn = make_enemies()
enemy_list.append(spawn)
add_enemy = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
pygame.time.set_timer(add_enemy, 1000)

# Game loop
done = False
while not done:

    # RGB - RED, GREEN, BLUE (0-255)
    screen.fill(BACKGROUND)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
        if event.type == add_enemy:
            spawn = make_enemies()
            enemy_list.append(spawn)
    for enemy in enemy_list:
        enemy.x = enemy.change_x
        enemy.y = enemy.change_y
        pygame.draw.circle (screen, WHITE, [enemy.change_x, enemy.change_y], BALL_SIZE)


    enemy.update()
    clock.tick(100)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling enemy.update() outside of your for loop. So, only the last enemy in the list is updating. Moving it inside your for loop should take care of it.

```
    for enemy in enemy_list:
       enemy.x = enemy.change_x
       enemy.y = enemy.change_y
       pygame.draw.circle (screen, WHITE, [enemy.change_x, 
       enemy.change_y], BALL_SIZE)
       enemy.update()
```